# ASP NET when i try save db, i get the error Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial140.dll'

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I have site on local machine and when i try callout db.SaveChanges(), i get the error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." Inner exception: DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial140.dll': Single module not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).
But the same code work perfect on global machine. Why i can got the error?
File that wrote in exception available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I donwload this dll files (32 bit and 64 bit) - msvcp120, sqlserverspatial140 on the site: https://www.dll-files.com/
and rewrite in the folders System32(64 bit) and SysWow64(32 bit).